# Counting the cost of nested for loops

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to count the cost of the following algorithm in terms of a function of n.

```
for i:= 1 to n do
  for j:= i to n do
    k:=0
```

I understand that the inner for loop will iterate (n-1) + (n-2) + .... (n-n) times, however I don't know how to express this mathematically in a simpler form. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(n-1) + (n-2) + .... (n-n)` is equal to the sum of all integers from 0 to N-1. So it is equal to the N-1th [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), which can be found with the formula

```
Tn = n * (n+1) / 2
```

Which is equivalent to (1/2)*n^2 + (1/2)*n.

When calculating Big O complexity, you discard constant multipliers and all but the fastest-growing component, so an algorithm that takes `(1/2)*n^2 + (1/2)*n` steps to execute runs in O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop, on average iterates (≈½n) times.
In "Big O" notation, you only care about the largest factor.
That is, for example, if you have:

n³ + n + log(n) + 1234

then the only thing that matters is the n³ factor, so O(n³).

So in your case:

½n x n = ½n²

which is O(n²) because the ½ doesn't matter.